# routing table, ip address for outgoing packet

Tags: router, ip, routing, subnet

```
Network Destination             Netmask                 Gateway          Interface    
          0.0.0.0                   0.0.0.0             192.168.2.1          192.168.2.8          
        127.0.0.0         255.0.0.0                         On-link             127.0.0.1        
        127.0.0.1                 255.255.255.255           On-link             127.0.0.1         
  127.255.255.255                 255.255.255.255           On-link             127.0.0.1        
      192.168.2.0                255.255.255.0              On-link         192.168.2.8           
      192.168.2.8                255.255.255.255            On-link         192.168.2.8           
    192.168.2.255                255.255.255.255            On-link         192.168.2.8           
        224.0.0.0           240.0.0.0                       On-link             127.0.0.1                
        224.0.0.0           240.0.0.0                       On-link         192.168.2.8           
  255.255.255.255               255.255.255.255             On-link             127.0.0.1              
  255.255.255.255               255.255.255.255             On-link             192.168.2.8
```

Based on the routing table information above, what IP address would traffic destined for an external network be sent to, and what interface device?

IP Address of next node:

Interface device:

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: yes, wifi network

Comment: If you have questions that are homework, please mention that in your post. Also, you should show what exactly you've already tried. Especially with homework questions, we expect you to show your own research and tell us what you didn't understand and what you need help with. Having other people write out the full answer for you won't help you in the long run—ideally you should learn something from asking, which also involves researching (and asking a good question) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination *0.0.0.0* with mask *0.0.0.0* matches **any** address. The gateway mentioned next to it, 192.168.2.1, is thus the *default gateway*. Your interface connected to this gateway has address 192.168.2.8, but the routing table does not specify whether this is an ethernet or wireless interface. Other possibilities (like a VPN) are inconsistent with the table.

Comment: this is wireless network. So i I were to uploading a file to some external network, what IP address would the traffic be sent to? and what interface would be used?

Comment: @SariksaThapa Like I said in my answer, it will be sent to 192.168.2.1, and the interface that will be used is the one which has IP address 192.168.2.8. You can check which interface that is with the command ifconfig, searching for one that says: inet: 192.168.2.8